# Ionic framework maintain view state

Tags: angularjs, view, dictionary, tabs, state

I have a tab in my Ionic project which consists of a map. On that map, the user can pan around and do things such as draw polygons, etc.

However, when the user moves to another tab and comes back, the map is completely reset and all his work is gone, because Angular seems to destroy the state. In addition, another request will have to be made to the map tile server because of this, which can be expensive (financially) for the company.

Is there a way to tell Angular not to reset the state when navigating from tab to tab? Or perhaps this project isn't a good fit for Angular based technologies?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the map is being created in your scenario, but have you tried nesting your states? http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/ has a great example of a nested state that shares data between them. You might also look into the $cacheFactory service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory and use it to store and retrieve your map.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Caching and routing can, with some work, maintain state to some extent (but nothing too graphically complex). Also, unfortunately I need the map to keep updating itself in the background.